# delegate c# to share data between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance, closures

i have this assignement when i need to create a winform of all classes that i ve implementedalready did form add but got issues in my list form cant access list of borrowers from form add1

here is my form list1.cs

namespace TP.A {
public partial class list1 : Form{

private Button Exit;
private GestionEmprunteur _gestionEmprunteur;

```
public list1()
{
    _gestionEmprunteur = new GestionEmprunteur();
    InitializeComponent_D();
    InitializeDataGridView();
    // Abonnement à l'événement OnAddEmprunteur de l'objet add1
    add1 addForm = new add1();
    addForm.OnAddEmprunteur += AddEmprunteur;
}
private DataGridView dgvBorrowers;

private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    {
        //create DataGridView to display borrowers
        dgvBorrowers = new DataGridView();
        dgvBorrowers.Location = new Point(100,200);
       dgvBorrowers.Size = new Size(798, 450);
        dgvBorrowers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvBorrowers.DataSource = _gestionEmprunteur.Lister2();
        this.Controls.Add(dgvBorrowers);

    }
}


private void AddEmprunteur(Emprunteur emprunteur)
{
    _gestionEmprunteur.AddEmprunteur(emprunteur);
    dgvBorrowers.DataSource = _gestionEmprunteur.Lister2();
}


private void InitializeComponent_D()
{

  //  DESIGN1.ApplyDesign(this);
    //create submit button
    Exit = new Button();
    Exit.Text = "Exit";
    Exit.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    Exit.Location = new Point((this.Width - Exit.Width) / 2, 500);
    Exit.Size = new Size(100, 50);
    Exit.Click += new EventHandler(exit_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(Exit);
    Exit.BringToFront();
    Exit.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
    
}

private void exit_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
} }}
```

here is my form add1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Validation.services;
using serie2.Validation.services;
using TP.main;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TP.A
{
    public partial class add1 : Form
    {

        public delegate void AddEmprunteurHandler(Emprunteur emprunteur);
        public event AddEmprunteurHandler OnAddEmprunteur;
        private Emprunteur emprunteur;
        private GestionEmprunteur _gestionEmprunteur;
        private TextBox _nameTextBox;
        private TextBox _firstNameTextBox;
        private Button _submitButton;
        private Button _cancelButton;
        private Label _nameLabel;
        private Label _loginLabel;
        private Label _firstNameLabel;
        private List<Emprunteur> _emprunteurs;

        public add1()
        {
            _emprunteurs = new List<Emprunteur>();

            _gestionEmprunteur = new GestionEmprunteur();
           
            InitializeComponent(this);

        }


        private void InitializeComponent( Form form)
        {
            DESIGN1.ApplyDesign(this);

            //create label for name
            Label loginLabel = new Label();
            loginLabel.Text = "Login :";
            loginLabel.Left = 0;
            loginLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            loginLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            loginLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            loginLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - loginLabel.Width) / 2, 100);
            loginLabel.Font = new Font("Andalus", 22, FontStyle.Bold);

            loginLabel.AutoSize = true;
            //   nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            this.Controls.Add(loginLabel);
            loginLabel.BringToFront();


            //create label for name
            Label nameLabel = new Label();
            nameLabel.Text = "Name:";
            nameLabel.Left = 0 ;
            nameLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            nameLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            nameLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            nameLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman",16 ,FontStyle.Bold);
            nameLabel.AutoSize = true;
         //   nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            this.Controls.Add(nameLabel);
            nameLabel.BringToFront();

            //create textbox for name
            _nameTextBox = new TextBox();
           // _nameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 30);
            _nameTextBox.Location = new Point((form.Width - _nameTextBox.Width) / 2, 300);
            _nameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 25);
            form.Controls.Add(_nameTextBox);
            _nameTextBox.BringToFront();

            //create label for first name
            Label firstNameLabel = new Label();
            firstNameLabel.Text = "First Name:";
            firstNameLabel.Left = 0;
            firstNameLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            firstNameLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            firstNameLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            firstNameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - firstNameLabel.Width) / 2, 350);
            firstNameLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            firstNameLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(firstNameLabel);
            firstNameLabel.BringToFront();

            //create textbox for first name
            _firstNameTextBox = new TextBox();
          
            _firstNameTextBox.Location = new Point((form.Width - _firstNameTextBox.Width) / 2, 400);
            _firstNameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 25);
            form.Controls.Add(_firstNameTextBox);
            _firstNameTextBox.BringToFront();


            //create submit button
            _submitButton = new Button();
            _submitButton.Text = "Submit";
            _submitButton.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
            _submitButton.Location = new Point((form.Width - _submitButton.Width) / 2, 500);
            _submitButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            _submitButton.Click += new EventHandler(SubmitButton_Click);
            form.Controls.Add(_submitButton);
            _submitButton.BringToFront();
            _submitButton.RightToLeft= RightToLeft.Yes;

         

            //create cancel button
            _cancelButton = new Button();
            _cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
            _cancelButton.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
            _cancelButton.Location = new Point((form.Width - _submitButton.Width) / 180, 500);
            _cancelButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            _cancelButton.Click += new EventHandler(cancel_Click);
            form.Controls.Add(_cancelButton);
            _cancelButton.BringToFront();





    }

    private void cancel_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            
            
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_nameTextBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_firstNameTextBox.Text))
            {
                Emprunteur emp = new Emprunteur { Nom = _nameTextBox.Text, Prenom = _firstNameTextBox.Text };
                
                bool success = _gestionEmprunteur.AddEmprunteur(emp);
                // Appel de l'événement OnAddEmprunteur
                OnAddEmprunteur?.Invoke(emp);

                if (success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Borrower added successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    

                    _nameTextBox.Text = "";
                    _firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while adding the borrower.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

              
                _gestionEmprunteur.Lister();

                


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name and first name for the borrower.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        


    }
}
```

HERE ARE THE MODICATION THAT I UNCLUDED i want to share data of datagrid from my form add1.cs to my form list1.cs i added a datagrid in my form1 to ensure that my data are displayed correctly
but m facing issues to connect both forms

```
public partial class add1 : Form
    {

       
        private Emprunteur emprunteur;
        static  GestionEmprunteur _gestionEmprunteur;
        private TextBox _nameTextBox;
        private TextBox _firstNameTextBox;
        private Button _submitButton;
        private Button _cancelButton;
        private Label _nameLabel;
        private Label _loginLabel;
        private Label _firstNameLabel;
        static List<Emprunteur> _emprunteurs;
        private DataGridView dgvBorrowers;

        public add1()
        {

            dgvBorrowers = new DataGridView();
            dgvBorrowers.Location = new Point(40, 190);
            dgvBorrowers.Size = new Size(450, 300);
            dgvBorrowers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.Controls.Add(dgvBorrowers);
            _emprunteurs = new List<Emprunteur>();

            _gestionEmprunteur = new GestionEmprunteur();

            InitializeComponent(this);

        }


        private void InitializeComponent(Form form)
        {
            DESIGN1.ApplyDesign(this);

            //create label for name
            Label loginLabel = new Label();
            loginLabel.Text = "Login :";
            loginLabel.Left = 0;
            loginLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            loginLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            loginLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            loginLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - loginLabel.Width) / 2, 100);
            loginLabel.Font = new Font("Andalus", 22, FontStyle.Bold);

            loginLabel.AutoSize = true;
            //   nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            this.Controls.Add(loginLabel);
            loginLabel.BringToFront();


            //create label for name
            Label nameLabel = new Label();
            nameLabel.Text = "Name:";
            nameLabel.Left = 0;
            nameLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            nameLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            nameLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            nameLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            nameLabel.AutoSize = true;
            //   nameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - nameLabel.Width) / 2, 250);
            this.Controls.Add(nameLabel);
            nameLabel.BringToFront();

            //create textbox for name
            _nameTextBox = new TextBox();
            // _nameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 30);
            _nameTextBox.Location = new Point((form.Width - _nameTextBox.Width) / 2, 300);
            _nameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 25);
            form.Controls.Add(_nameTextBox);
            _nameTextBox.BringToFront();

            //create label for first name
            Label firstNameLabel = new Label();
            firstNameLabel.Text = "First Name:";
            firstNameLabel.Left = 0;
            firstNameLabel.ForeColor = Color.White;

            firstNameLabel.BackColor = Color.Black;
            firstNameLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0);
            firstNameLabel.Location = new Point((form.Width - firstNameLabel.Width) / 2, 350);
            firstNameLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            firstNameLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(firstNameLabel);
            firstNameLabel.BringToFront();

            //create textbox for first name
            _firstNameTextBox = new TextBox();

            _firstNameTextBox.Location = new Point((form.Width - _firstNameTextBox.Width) / 2, 400);
            _firstNameTextBox.Size = new Size(150, 25);
            form.Controls.Add(_firstNameTextBox);
            _firstNameTextBox.BringToFront();


            //create submit button
            _submitButton = new Button();
            _submitButton.Text = "Submit";
            _submitButton.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
            _submitButton.Location = new Point((form.Width - _submitButton.Width) / 2, 500);
            _submitButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            _submitButton.Click += new EventHandler(SubmitButton_Click);
            form.Controls.Add(_submitButton);
            _submitButton.BringToFront();
            _submitButton.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;



            //create cancel button
            _cancelButton = new Button();
            _cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
            _cancelButton.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
            _cancelButton.Location = new Point((form.Width - _submitButton.Width) / 180, 500);
            _cancelButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            _cancelButton.Click += new EventHandler(cancel_Click);
            form.Controls.Add(_cancelButton);
            _cancelButton.BringToFront();





        }

        private void cancel_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_nameTextBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_firstNameTextBox.Text))
            {
                Emprunteur emp = new Emprunteur(_nameTextBox.Text, _firstNameTextBox.Text);

                bool success = _gestionEmprunteur.AddEmprunteur(emp);
                if (success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Borrower added successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    dgvBorrowers.DataSource = _gestionEmprunteur._emprunteurs;
                    _nameTextBox.Text = "";
                    _firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while adding the borrower.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name and first name for the borrower.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }





 public list1()
        {
            _gestionEmprunteur = new GestionEmprunteur();
            InitializeComponent_D();
            InitializeDataGridView();
        }


        private void InitializeDataGridView()
        {
            dgvBorrowers = new DataGridView();
            dgvBorrowers.Location = new Point(100, 200);
            dgvBorrowers.Size = new Size(798, 450);
            dgvBorrowers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgvBorrowers.DataSource = _gestionEmprunteur._emprunteurs;
            this.Controls.Add(dgvBorrowers);
        }
```

Comment: [Using Action (delegate) or Event to communicate between form and controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484034/3110834). Same can be used for two forms.

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834). Explaining different solutions to pass data between forms.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: well i tried the delegate method but didnt work gave me so many errors also i tried to affect the list in the constructor of form2 list1.cs as paramater still not working